# ¿Puedo hacer un doble reduce en Javascript?

Tags: javascript, programación-funcional

Tengo un arreglo de arreglos (con elementos booleanos), digamos,

```
const array = [[false, false], [false, true], [true, true]];
```

Y quiero usar un `reduce()` para contar cuantos true hay, esto es lo que intento:

```
const check = (array) => {
    const numNotAnsweredQuestion = array.reduce((acc, elem1) => {
      return (
        acc +
        elem1.reduce((acc2, elem2) => {
          return elem2 ? acc2 + 1 : acc2;
        }, 0)
      );
    }, 0);
    return numNotAnsweredQuestion;
  };
```

Es decir, acumulo doblemente, ¿o no?

El navegador me devuelve la función:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Creo que faltan los paréntesis: **return numNotAnsweredQuestion();**

Comment: Pero el reduce debería devolver el valor del acumulador, ¿no? Entonces sería más un número que una función.

Comment: numNotAnsweredQuestion te devuelve el valor de la constante (código de función), con los paréntesis se ejecuta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu función funciona. Me da la idea que sólo te falta invocarla. **Pero**... es una mala práctica hacer shadowing de variables/parámetros. Mejor usar, dentro de la función, variables que no se llamen igual que las de fuera.

Dicho esto, el approach:

```js
const array_original = [
  [false, false],
  [false, true],
  [true, true]
];

const check = (array_cualquiera) => {
  const numNotAnsweredQuestion = array_cualquiera.reduce((acc, elem1) => {
    return (
      acc +
      elem1.reduce((acc2, elem2) => {
        return elem2 ? acc2 + 1 : acc2;
      }, 0)
    );
  }, 0);
  return numNotAnsweredQuestion;
};

// Imprime 3
console.log(check(array_original));
```

Está perfecto. Sin embargo estás operando sobre un array que conoces y tu implementación es una solución particular.

Si en cambio tuvieses un array del cual sólo te consta que tiene elementos en niveles de anidación de profundidad N, y quisieras contar

- cuantos son `truthy` ( strings no vacíos, true, números distintos a cero, objetos) o
- cuantos son `falsy` (strings vacíos, null, undefined, 0, false,NaN)

Puedes usar recursividad para reinvocar la función `countTruthy` sobre todo elemento anidado que sea un array, y mapear `truthy` a 1 y `falsy`a 0 en caso contrario:

```js
const countTruthy = (array_cualquiera) => {
  return array_cualquiera.reduce((acc, elem1) => {
      return acc + 
      ((Array.isArray(elem1) && countTruthy(elem1))  // recursión
      || (elem1 ? 1 : 0)); //mapeo
      
   }, 0);
};

const array_original = [
  [false, false],
  [false, true],
  [true, true]
];
// Sigue siendo 3
console.log(countTruthy(array_original));

const array_muy_anidado = [
  [true, 1, 0],
  [undefined, false, NaN, window, Infinity],
  [
    [null, true], ''
  ],
  ['yes', [-1, 0, [{}, new Map(), function() {}]]]
];

// Imprime 10
console.log(countTruthy(array_muy_anidado));
```

Este planteamiento funciona sobre tu array de ejemplo y en general sobre cualquier array cuyos elementos puedas coercionar a un booleano

Comment: Interesante... Gracias por las recomendaciones.

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que se debe considerar lo siguiente:

- Tienes una matriz de datos (este detalle es importante pues primero debes acceder a los valores contenidos)
- Primero debes iterar al menos 2 veces para obtener los valores de cada vector contenido en la matriz
- Cuando obtengas los valores de cada vector de la matriz, entonces los puedes agregar a un vector vacío (paso )
- Una vez que tienes el vector nuevo con todos los valores extraidos de la matriz, entonces puedes aplicar el método **`reduce`**
- No veo por que usar 2 `reduce` ya que la intención de este es reducir a un elemento un **vector** mas no de una **matriz**, dado eso no me parece el modo correcto de querer implementarlo

Código de ejemplo

```js
    const array = [[false, false], [false, true], [true, true]]
    let nuevoArray = []
    
    for (elemento of array) {
      for(valor of elemento) {
        nuevoArray.push(valor)
      }
    }
    
    let sumaEnteros = nuevoArray.reduce((previo, actual) => previo + actual)
    console.log(sumaEnteros)
```

Answer (score 1):

Con pasarle la función que compruebe si el valor es true y en ese caso sumar uno al acumulador debería bastar:

```js
const array = [[false, false], [false, true], [true, true]];

console.log(array.reduce((a,b)=>b?a+1:a, 0));
```

De todas formas, lo puedes hacer de una forma más sencilla utilizando flat y filter:

```js
const array = [[false, false], [false, true], [true, true]];

console.log(array.flat().filter(v => v).length)
```

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo que la forma mas corta y eficiente es hacer `.flat` y luego `.reduce`:

```js
const array = [[false, false], [false, true], [true, true]];

const res = array.flat().reduce((p,c)=>p+c);

console.log(res);
```

Los `false` serán 0 y los `true` 1. Esto es válido solo si los valores son `true` o `false`.